# Transform data frame to a different form

Tags: python, dataframe, columnsorting

This is my data frame.

| Date | Country | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/4/1971 | Sweden | 5.1643 |
| 1/5/1971 | Sweden | 5.1628 |
| 1/6/1971 | Sweden | 5.1614 |
| 1/7/1971 | Sweden | 5.1649 |
| 1/8/1971 | Sweden | 5.1631 |
| 1/4/1971 | Canada | 1.0109 |
| 1/5/1971 | Canada | 1.0102 |
| 1/6/1971 | Canada | 1.0106 |
| 1/7/1971 | Canada | 1.0148 |
| 1/8/1971 | Canada | 1.0154 |
| 1/4/1971 | India | 8.02 |
| 1/5/1971 | India | 8.00 |
| 1/6/1971 | India | 8.01 |
| 1/7/1971 | India | 8.00 |
| 1/8/1971 | India | 8.03 |

I want above data frame like bellow using python and panda.

| Date | Sweden | Canada | India |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/4/1971 | 5.1643 | 1.0109 | 8.02 |
| 1/5/1971 | 5.1628 | 1.0102 | 8 |
| 1/6/1971 | 5.1614 | 1.0106 | 8.01 |
| 1/7/1971 | 5.1649 | 1.0148 | 8 |
| 1/8/1971 | 5.1631 | 1.0154 | 8.03 |

Please help me.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we create your dataframe for test..

```
import pandas as pd

arr = [['1/4/1971', 'Sweden', '5.1643'],
       ['1/5/1971', 'Sweden', '5.1628'],
       ['1/6/1971', 'Sweden', '5.1614'],
       ['1/7/1971', 'Sweden', '5.1649'],
       ['1/8/1971', 'Sweden', '5.1631'],
       ['1/4/1971', 'Canada', '1.0109'],
       ['1/5/1971', 'Canada', '1.0102'],
       ['1/6/1971', 'Canada', '1.0106'],
       ['1/7/1971', 'Canada', '1.0148'],
       ['1/8/1971', 'Canada', '1.0154'],
       ['1/4/1971', 'India', '8.02'],
       ['1/5/1971', 'India', '8.00'],
       ['1/6/1971', 'India', '8.01'],
       ['1/7/1971', 'India', '8.00'],
       ['1/8/1971', 'India', '8.03']]
df = pd.DataFrame(arr,columns=['Date','Country','Value'])
print('old form')
print(df)
```

The output should be like:

```
old form
        Date Country   Value
0   1/4/1971  Sweden  5.1643
1   1/5/1971  Sweden  5.1628
2   1/6/1971  Sweden  5.1614
3   1/7/1971  Sweden  5.1649
4   1/8/1971  Sweden  5.1631
5   1/4/1971  Canada  1.0109
6   1/5/1971  Canada  1.0102
7   1/6/1971  Canada  1.0106
8   1/7/1971  Canada  1.0148
9   1/8/1971  Canada  1.0154
10  1/4/1971   India    8.02
11  1/5/1971   India    8.00
12  1/6/1971   India    8.01
13  1/7/1971   India    8.00
14  1/8/1971   India    8.03
```

Let's do our magic:

> note: this code not optimized but works well

```
table = {}
for row in df.values:
    date = row[0]
    country = row[1]
    value = row[2]
    if date not in table:table[date] = {country:value}
    else:table[date][country] = value

arr = []
for date in table.keys():
    row = table[date]
    row = [date,row['Sweden'],row['Canada'],row['India']]
    arr.append(row)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(arr,columns=['Date','Sweden','Canada','India'])
print('new form')
print(df2)
```

The final output should be

```
new form
       Date  Sweden  Canada India
0  1/4/1971  5.1643  1.0109  8.02
1  1/5/1971  5.1628  1.0102  8.00
2  1/6/1971  5.1614  1.0106  8.01
3  1/7/1971  5.1649  1.0148  8.00
4  1/8/1971  5.1631  1.0154  8.03
```

Comment: Hi Aly, Thank you very much for your answer. I wanted to created new columns(country names) dynamically but you created it statically. I waned the way @Norie  answered. Anyway thank you very much for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with the `pivot` method of the dataframe.

### Code

The following code assumes the original data is in a file named `test.csv`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

print(df)

df = df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Country', values = 'Value').reset_index()

print(df)
```

### Before

| Date | Country | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/4/1971 | Sweden | 5.1643 |
| 1/5/1971 | Sweden | 5.1628 |
| 1/6/1971 | Sweden | 5.1614 |
| 1/7/1971 | Sweden | 5.1649 |
| 1/8/1971 | Sweden | 5.1631 |
| 1/4/1971 | Canada | 1.0109 |
| 1/5/1971 | Canada | 1.0102 |
| 1/6/1971 | Canada | 1.0106 |
| 1/7/1971 | Canada | 1.0148 |
| 1/8/1971 | Canada | 1.0154 |
| 1/4/1971 | India | 8.02 |
| 1/5/1971 | India | 8 |
| 1/6/1971 | India | 8.01 |
| 1/7/1971 | India | 8 |
| 1/8/1971 | India | 8.03 |

### After

| Country | Date | Canada | India | Sweden |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1/4/1971 | 1.0109 | 8.02 | 5.1643 |
| 1 | 1/5/1971 | 1.0102 | 8 | 5.1628 |
| 2 | 1/6/1971 | 1.0106 | 8.01 | 5.1614 |
| 3 | 1/7/1971 | 1.0148 | 8 | 5.1649 |
| 4 | 1/8/1971 | 1.0154 | 8.03 | 5.1631 |

Comment: Hi Norie, Thank you very much for your answer. It really easy and works.